# Android viewbinding deprecation warning persists in Android Studio 4 after making appropriate update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating to Androis Studio 4.0 I received a warning that `android.viewBinding.enabled` was deprecated and shoud lbe replaces with `android.buildFeatures.viewBinding`.

I therefoe changed the appropraiet part of my `build.gradle (app)` from:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enable = true
    }
    ...
}
```

to:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I no longer get the warning, but still get an information box in my build window as follows:

`build.gradle: DSL element 'android.viewBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.viewBinding'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.`

Is this normal? I knows it's not a warning or an error, but it seems odd to tell me about something that has been fixed - or have I not fixed it correctly (my app still works using viewBinding as expected).

(Note also that when adding the `buildFeatures` section to the file, none of the required entires, including `buildFeatures` pops up in teh auto-complete prompt.)

[image: Info item in Android Studio build panel]

Comment: Clear and invalidate cache?

Comment: Already tried that. Also, when adding the `buildFeatures` section nothing comes up in auto-complete - it's almost like this change hasn't been fully implemented... (I shoud add that to the question...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it!

Although it was working - i.e. the View bindings were working fine - the correct new syntax appears to be:

```
android
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    ...
}
```

...still not popping up in the auto-complete, though.

---

Update: After a few buids and rebuilds I checked again and now `buildFeatures` IS popping up in teh auto-complete... Guess I wasn't being patient enough for everything to catch up. Just a bit odd that invalidating the caches didn't fix the auto-complete straight away.

Answer (score 1):

@Fat Monk

Please add this line to your app build.gradle file.

```
android.buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
```

Comment: Thanks, that syntax also seems to work, but I'd prefer to stick to the bracketted format of the rest of my build.gradle.

Comment: @FatMonk Please update the below line in your gradle-wrapper.properties file.


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had also this warning.

To solve it, I had just to remove from my build gradle (module app) this old line :

```
viewBinding.enabled = true
```

and I replaced it with :

```
android.buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
```